# The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance in Kendo Angular DatePicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Binding for kendo DatePicker has an error.

> The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance

my web api in asp core to get a student is :

```
    [HttpGet, Route("/api/master/{id}")]
    public JsonResult GetStudentById(int id)
    {
        return Json(new { id = 1, RegisterDate = DateTime.Now });
    }
```

it returns :

```
{"id":1,"registerDate":"2018-05-01T13:23:35.1229748+04:30"}
```

and finally in my angular component is :

```
student: Student = new Student();
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.http
       .get(`http://localhost:58824/api/master/${10}`, { headers: this.setHeader() })
       .subscribe(response => { this.student = response; });
}
```

view :

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm" (submit)="save(form)">
   <label for="birthDate">Date</label>
   <kendo-datepicker [format]="'dd-MM-yyyy'" name="registerDate" [(ngModel)]="student.registerDate"></kendo-datepicker>
</form>
```

there is an error :
**The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance**

needless to say, I have added DateInputsModule to imports array in app.module
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This config removes the timezone (+04:30) from the serialized data:

```
services.AddMvc()  
       .AddJsonOptions(options =>  
       {  
         options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;  // Treat as a local time if a DateTime is being converted to a string.
       });
```

Or try specifying the DateTimeFormat this way and make it automatically adjust dates to UTC by setting DateTimeStyles to AdjustToUniversal:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        var settings = options.SerializerSettings;
        var dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK"
        };
        settings.Converters.Add(dateConverter);
    });
```

Comment: thanks my master for replying, but I still have that error after applying the config above and needless to say DateTimeZoneHandling is an enum and I can not set the string for that! is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Use `DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified` if you want to just convert the date to a string. more info: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Answer (score 1):

The value used in the `kendo-datepicker` must be of type `Date` but in your case it is a `string`.

You need to convert it to a valid `Date` object beforehand.
This can be done with e.g. a [JSON Reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), or by utilizing the `IntlService.parseDate` method ([Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/internationalization/parsing-and-formatting/#toc-date-parsing)).

```
@Component({ ... })
public class MyComponent
{
    value: Date;
    valueString: string;

    constructor(private intl: IntlService) {
        this.value = this.intl.parseDate("2018-05-01T13:23:35.1229748+04:30");
        this.valueString = "2018-05-01T13:23:35.1229748+04:30"; 
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<!-- Works fine -->
<kendo-datepicker
    [(value)]="value"
></kendo-datepicker>

<!-- Throws error: The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance -->
<kendo-datepicker
    [(value)]="valueString"
></kendo-datepicker>
```

You can also find an example of a possible implementation over at KendoUIs documentation ([Link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/integration-with-json/))